# ToastNotification doesn't show up immediately?

Tags: c#, windows-8, toast

I tried to work a bit with Windows 8 Apps and created a testapp.
First I wanted to try out the new ToastNotifications and let the app create one on a button click event:

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        XmlDocument x = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastText01);
        XmlNodeList toastTextElements = x.GetElementsByTagName("text");
        toastTextElements[0].AppendChild(x.CreateTextNode("TestNotification" + DateTime.Now.ToString()));
        ToastNotification toast = new ToastNotification(x);
        ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
    }
```

So why did I add DateTime.Now.ToString()?
I noticed that the Toast isn't showed immediately if I press my button but sometimes 30 Secs or more later.

For example if I click at 11:00:00a.m. the notification appears at 11:00:22a.m.
Sometimes it shows immediately but maybe in 2/10 clicks.

Is there a solution to this?
Is it maybe a bug?

Comment: When you see this behavior, are any other toasts on screen when the button is clicked?

Comment: No there are no others but if I click several time on my button then there are after this random period of time :D

Comment: Only three toasts can be on screen at the same time.  Windows will queue up other toasts until those on screen timeout.

Comment: ok but there are no other toasts on app startup?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your last comment.

Comment: I just said that there are no other toast when starting my app.
At the moment my problem seems to be solved. I don't know why but it works now to show toasts without any delay.